# PHP: Insert separated comma string value with as multiple array value Into MySql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, mysqli

Here is my goal
1. I have only one ID send from the server with list of string separated comma
        this how it look like: ID=1, names=blue,red,green,yellow
2. This is my attempt:
       2.1 i try to change the names to arrays by using this code

```
$myString = "Red,Blue,Black";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
```

2.2 and i try my insertion like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `cat_interest`(`id`,`categories`) VALUES (1,'".$myArray["categories"]."'";
            if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                    $message = array('Message' => 'insert fail');
                    echo json_encode($message);         
            }else{             
                    $message = array('Message' => 'new record inserted');
                    echo json_encode($tempArray);     
            }
```

Here is my complete code view

```
 <?php
define('HOST','serveraddress');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','pass');
define('DB','dbname');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
    $message= array();      
        $myString = "Red,Blue,Black";// incoming string comma names
        $myArray = explode(',', $myString); 

       $sql="INSERT INTO `cat_interest`(`id`,`categories`) VALUES (1,'".$myArray["categories"]."'";
                if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                        $message= array('Message' => 'insertion failed');
                        echo json_encode($message);         
                }else{             
                        $message= array('Message' => 'new record inserted');
                        echo json_encode($message);   
                } ?>
```

This is what i want to achieve below 
   
TABLE
     ID     Categories
     1              RED
     1              Blue
     1              Black

after insertion

Please help i don't know what i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that SQL is invalid, you never close the `values`. Explode also doesn't build an associated array.

A rough example of how you could build a valid SQL statement would be

```
$myString = "Red,Blue,Black";// incoming string comma names
$myArray = explode(',', $myString); 
print_r($myArray);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cat_interest`(`id`,`categories`) VALUES";
foreach($myArray as $value){
    $sql .= " (1, '{$value}'),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
```

Demo: https://eval.in/587840

When in doubt about how an array in constructed use `print_r` or `var_dump`. When having an issue with a query in mysqli use error reporting, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Also in your current usage you aren't open to SQL injections but if `$myString` comes from user input, or your DB you could be. You should look into using parameterized queries; http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: wow this is awesome, but if what if i want to check for duplicate value from comma separated spring before insertion?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php, demo: https://eval.in/587857.