# Insert multiple rows using single query PHP (Prepared statements)

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to insert multiple rows in single query using PHP prepared statements?

I have this multidimensional data:

```
$data = array(
'6' => array(
  '945' => array(
    '11:04' => array(
      '0' => array(
        'date' => '2013-02-02',
        'user' => '3'
      ),
    ),
    '11:05' => array(
      '0' => array(
        'date' => '2013-02-03',
        'user' => '3'
       ),
    ),
    '11:06' => array(
      '0' => array(
        'date' => '2013-02-03',
        'user' => '3'
       ),
    )
  )
);
```

And the query I used is :

`$ins = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table  (date, user) VALUES ('2013-02-03', '03' )");
 $ins->execute();`

The query above is working but it just insert only one row so I tried to used the foreach as below:

```
 foreach ($data as $dk => $dv) {
    foreach ($dv as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $rk => $rv) {
           $ins = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table  (date, user) VALUES ($rv['date'], $rv['user'] )");
            $ins->execute();

        }
    }
}
```

I want to query as:

`INSERT INTO emp (date,user) VALUES("2013-02-02",3),("2013-02-02",3),("2013-02-03",3);`

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Insert separated comma string value with as multiple array value Into MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780041/php-insert-separated-comma-string-value-with-as-multiple-array-value-into-mysql) Also note your current `prepared` usage is incorrect. Variables shouldn't be in your query.

Comment: First, let's be sure that your query is what you think it is.  `$query="INSERT..."`, then echo that `$query`.  Does it look OK?  What happens when you type the same string into SQL -- does it work?  What does `$ins->execute()` return?  You can `print_r` it to find out.