# how to add comma in query for next item?

Tags: php, mysql

how to add comma in query for next item? Add more details to the question.

```
// Indented the codes to make it more readable
$participants = [602, 600];

$query      = array();
$query[]    = 'INSERT INTO ' . 
             $db->nameQuote( '#__social_conversations_participants' );
$query[]    = '(' . $db->nameQuote( 'conversation_id' ) .',' . 
             $db->nameQuote( 'user_id' ) . ',' . $db->nameQuote( 'state' ) . ')';
$query[]    = 'VALUES';
foreach( $participants as $userId ){
    $query[]    = '(' . $db->Quote( $conversationId ) . ',' . 
                  $db->Quote( $userId ) . ',' . $db->Quote( 1 ) . ')';
```

> //this is not working because next() in this case always return
>   false

```
    // Indented the codes to make it more readable
    if( next( $participants ) !== false ){
        $query[]    = ',';
    }
}
// Glue query back.
$query = implode( ' ' , $query );
var_dump($query);exit;
```

Comment: Put effort into your question.

Comment: what database library is that? does it have parameterized queries?

Comment: why are you building a query like this, why break it in to an array to just rejoin it?

Comment: @Isaac, its joomla

Comment: @Dagon, there are many ways of doing things..I resorted to do this way for some reason..If you have better way to do which would solve my problem, please share

Comment: @Darren, what kind of effort to show? I put the question as plain as possible so that it will not look complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution from here: [PHP: Insert separated comma string value with as multiple array value Into MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780041/php-insert-separated-comma-string-value-with-as-multiple-array-value-into-mysql)

```
<?php
    $myString = "Red,Blue,Black";// incoming string comma names
    $myArray = explode(',', $myString); 
    print_r($myArray);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `cat_interest`(`id`,`categories`) VALUES";
    foreach($myArray as $value){
        $sql .= " (1, '{$value}'),";
    }
    echo rtrim($sql, ',');
```